# arc42 template: Target architecture vs status quo

Tags: arc42

A colleague and I were wondering the following today: the documentation that one maintains based on this template is a living thing, and thus all the sections will be corrected and extended as the solution being built evolves. Is there a way to reflect the desired (maybe even utopic) architecture that we want to achieve, and at the same time document the status quo? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you are talking about a project where you document the architecture as you go and it seems that there are times where you decide not to go with the perfect/desired architecture, but implement a feature in another way for now...

Well I guess my descripten already contains the solution - you **decide** not to implement the desired solution. And this will be because of a constraint. So I would document this design decision in chapter 9 of the template and make sure that the constraints which cause the decision are documented in chapter 2. This way, you can revisit the contraints and decisions any time and check if it is time to change one of those.

Does this answer fit your question?

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was expecting more something like a dedicated section for an outlook on the future of the system, but keeping track of the decisions made as why the implementation is the way it is seems like a good, practicable approach. Thanks!